# How can i Plot percentage stack chart in Flot?

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

I am using Flot to plot graphs for my client side php's. In one graph i need Percentage Stack Graph, and i have found out that there is a plugin in Flot called [Percentage Stack Plugin](https://github.com/skeleton9/flot.stackpercent).

I want my Graph to be something like this.

[image: Expected Percentage Stack]

But when i implement the plugin i get something like this.

[image: Actual Percentage Stack]

I tried their example and its working fine. I think this problem is with the JSON data i pass.

My JSON looks like this.

```
  [{"data":[[-64.483189655172,74.483189655172]],"label":"machine_52"},{"data":[[-142.91077586207,152.91077586207]],"label":"machine_23"},{"data":[[-220.57456896552,230.57456896552]],"label":"machine_90"},{"data":[[-304.05043103448,314.05043103448]],"label":"machine_48"},{"data":[[-388.56163793103,398.56163793103]],"label":"machine_98"}]
```

X values are Uptime percentage and Y values DownTime Percentage. is those values should be less than 100 for ploting the graph.

My JS code looks like this.

```
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">  

$(document).ready(function(){
$.getJSON('barLine.txt', function(json) {

    $.plot($("#placeholder"),json, { series: {
        stackpercent: true,
        bars: { show: true, barWidth: 0.6, fillColor: {colors:[{opacity: 1},{opacity: 1}]}, align: "center" }
    },
    xaxis: {max:100},
    yaxis:{tickSize : 1}});
});
});

</script>
```

How can fix this bug

Comment: make the data structure match the data structure in working demo

Comment: By the way your script tag doesn't need `language="javascript"`

Comment: @charlietfl Actually i don't understand their data structure given in their example https://github.com/skeleton9/flot.stackpercent. They didn't pass percentage values in data, they just passes data like this [[0, null], [1, 1]]. How do i convert my data like this

Comment: In actual fact, the plugin will calculate the percentage for you. You just need to pass in the original data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK... How does the stackpercent plugin change your data?  What it does is add up the y values of everything with the same x value, and then create percentages based off of that.

For your case, what you want to do is have two series, one with all the uptime values, one with all the downtime values.  You line them up per machine, so that x = 0 in both series is the data for one of your machines.

Your data will look like this:

```
[
     {"label":"Down Time ","data":[[0,64],[1, 142],[2,220],[3,304],[4,388]],"color":"#B41722"},
     {"label":"Running Time","data":[[0, 74], [1, 152],[2,230],[3,314],[4,398]],"color":"#6A9A3C"} 
]
```

So you can see I've taken your `machine_52` data and split it into values in two series, the `-64.xxxxx` value is now `[0,64]` and it's corresponding `74.xxx` is in the 2nd series as `[0,74]`.

Then to connect that to the particular machine, you specify the `xaxis.ticks` option like this:

```
ticks: [[0,'Machine 52'],[1,'Machine 23'],[2,'Machine 90'],[3,'Machine 48'],[4,'Machine 98']]
```

The result looks like this:  http://jsfiddle.net/ryleyb/uSVvu/

Comment: Thanks Ryley, is it possible to provide add dynamic ticks with my JSON and use it rather than giving it statically. i tried to use it but it was not working for me. can u provide me a sample json for the above data with ticks. i also want horizontal percentage stack. i have been working with this problem for 2 day and i can't fix it.

Comment: You could generate all the flot data from your existing JSON (including the ticks array).  For horizontal, you would need to modify the percentstack plugin - it does not support this.  You could compare how it works to how the default stack plugin works, and modify from there...

Comment: I tried it earlier itself, But i was not able to access it inside my JS.

Comment: Hi, I'm author of the plugin. Ryley is right about it. The plugin add up the y values of everything with the same x value, and then create percentages based off of that. So, you need to group your data under the same x value to get it work.

Comment: I modified the json like this. `[
     {"label":"Down Time ","data":[[0,64],[1, 142],[2,220],[3,304],[4,388]],"color":"#B41722"},
     {"label":"Running Time","data":[[0, 74], [1, 152],[2,230],[3,314],[4,398]],"color":"#6A9A3C"},{ticks: [[0,'Machine 52'],[1,'Machine 23'],[2,'Machine 90'],[3,'Machine 48'],[4,'Machine 98']]} 
]`. but i was not able to access the ticks inside JS.